# In numpy, for an array of arrays, how do I use an array or start indices and an array of end indices to slice out a unique slice of each array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say that I have an array of arrays

```
array = np.random.randint(0, 6, (4, 6))
array
```

```
array([[3, 5, 2, 5, 1, 3],
       [5, 3, 0, 1, 4, 3],
       [2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 4],
       [2, 1, 0, 4, 2, 2]])
```

And I also have arrays for desired start and end indices for slicing out this array for each row

```
starts = np.random.randint(0, 3, (4,))
ends = starts + 3
ends
```

```
array([6, 3, 4, 3])
```

How do I slice out the array of arrays using these indices?

For the example, the desired result will be

```
array([[5, 1, 3],
       [5, 3, 0],
       [1, 0, 2],
       [2, 1, 0]])
```

something like `array[starts:ends]` does not work

Comment: Either iterate row by row, or index once with `[5,6,7, 3,4,5, 4,5,6, 3,4,5]`

Comment: I think you made a mistake in the example: it is either `array([6, 3, 4, 3])` or `array([5, 2, 3, 2])`, but the former is impossible with `np.random.randint(0, 3, (4,))` and the later impossible with `ends = starts + 3`. So I expect the desired result not to be possible with the provided information: the first line should be `2, 5, 1`.

Comment: @JérômeRichard sorry, I think it was an issue with double clicking a jupyter cell and not tracking the changes, I updated the post to reflect your statement.

Comment: It is still possible due to the second part of the previous comment. The last list is the one that matters the most ;) .

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but if this may help you:

```
a = []
i = 0
for s, e in zip(starts, ends):
    a.append(array[i][s:e])
    i += 1
```

Or use `enumerate()`

```
a = []
for i,(s, e) in enumerate(zip(starts, ends)):
    a.append(array[i][s:e])
```

then convert the list into an array to get the desired output

```
print(np.array(a))
```

It looks like this:

```
array([[2, 4, 2],
       [4, 3, 0],
       [2, 2, 0],
       [4, 0, 4]])
```

Comment: it's better to use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) than to do ```+=``` on a counting variable in a for loop

Comment: actually they have the same number of rows that's why I didn't use enumerate

Comment: what do you mean? I'm saying you should do ```for i, (s, e) in enumerate(zip(starts, ends)):``` and then get rid of ```i=0``` and ```i+=1```

Comment: yeah, that's a good option. I was thinking differently

Comment: Comprehension lists should be faster: `a = [array[i][s:e] for i,(s, e) in enumerate(zip(starts, ends))]`. `np.fromiter` without the list may be also even faster.